# Any way to call a method only when user clicks on an annotation pin?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, mkannotationview

I only want to execute a method call when the user clicks on a annotation pin on the map. I read the Apple documentation but am still unsure of how I can do it (or if this is even possible).

For example, I have created a restaurant class with a 'Distance from current location' property and the instances are added to a mapview as annotations. 
I only want to trigger the `calculateDistance` method when the user clicks on an annotation (and the callout view is displayed).

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view` in your MapView delegate.

The `MKAnnotationView` contains a property `annotation`.

Comment: thanks! However, I need the latest calculated value to be displayed in the annotation view. (stored as a property of my class). It seems that I need to click on the annotation again before the correct value is displayed. Is there a way to refresh the annotation view before the callout is displayed?

Comment: @Zhen In my situation, I still make use of didSelectAnnoationView. What I then do is obtain data (in this case a thumbnail from a server) then update the callout when I have retrieved the data. Showing a simple little animation for the update. Don't know if a similar solution will help. Because there is no other way to "predict" what annotation a user is going to select.